# Slow connection forces site to load without its style?

Tags: html, web

Why is it that when a webpage is loaded over a slow connection, sometimes it simply loads the 'bare' page without all the style (usually in times new roman)? And is it possible to purposely view a page in this state?

Comment: It's probably still downloading or applying the CSS from a separate file.

Comment: if the css doesn't load it doesn't style the page - you can force this simply by removing the `<link>` to the stylesheet (even if you do it via devtools)

Comment: To purposely view it, I use a Firefox addon called 'Web Developer' which adds a toolbar. From there you can disable all styles (or only inline, or only external, etc). Otherwise, you can comment out your CSS includes in the HTML

Comment: Simply because it runs into an error, timeout or something else, and than stops downloading (or downloading in the background) while outputing the page. I know this behaviour too, when the page fully loaded, but no styles applied, so I have to reload the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called an FOUC, flash of unstyled content, and developers usually go out of their way to keep this from happening. It happens when the html loads before the css has finished loading and it can usually be avoided by including links to external css files in the head of your page.

If you need to see it for some reason:

In Firefox go to View, Page Style, No style:

[image]